# Making python work with specific SSL shared object on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, ssl

As Python is modular, it loads shared object on run-time. Specifically, SSL shared object is not loaded until an "import ssl" command is executed.

I verified this with the following simple test.
I ran python and checked if ssl shared object was loaded:

```
vmmap 2287 | grep ssl
```

This has yielded an enpty output. Although, After performing "import ssl". I'm getting this output:

```
RegEPOSX2:~ root# vmmap 2287 | grep ssl
__TEXT                 0000000107d83000-0000000107d8d000 [   40K] r-x/rwx     SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
__LINKEDIT             0000000107d91000-0000000107d98000 [   28K] r--/rwx     SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
__TEXT                 00007fff8eca4000-00007fff8ecdd000 [  228K] r-x/r-x     SM=COW  /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
__DATA                 0000000107d8d000-0000000107d91000 [   16K] rw-/rwx     SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
__DATA                 00007fff97c14000-00007fff97c1a000 [   24K] rw-/rwx     SM=COW  /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
```

I have another shared object of ssl under another directory:

```
RegEPOSX2:~ root# ls -l /Library/ithak
total 5768
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       15 Dec  6 10:14 libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib -> libcrypto.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  2547424 Dec  6 10:12 libcrypto.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        6 Dec  6 10:13 libssl.0.9.8.dylib -> libssl
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   396112 Dec  6 10:12 libssl.dylib
```

I'm trying to make python use these shared object without compiling python with it (I don't want python to use them all the time).

I have already tried the following but to no avail:

1. Adding this path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in the beginning.
2. Adding this path to PYTHONPATH in the beginning.
3. Appending the path to sys.path in the beginning.

I keep seeing the same ssl shared object loaded upon call to vmmap instead of seeing my shared object loaded when calling to vmmap.

Is there anything else I can try ?

Comment: You will have to recompile/replace `_ssl.so` module as the only thing matters is what `libssl`/`libcrypto` headers were included/libs were linked on its compilation. Then insert path to your custom `_ssl.so` in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @hoefling
when _ssl.so is being dynamically loaded it suppose to have a search sequence for dynamic libraries.
I'm quite certain that it is possible to add the desired path to the sequence so it loads the shared objects I want it to.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with dynamic loading per se. If the library was linked hardcoded at build time (I suspect this is the case for you too), then you have no other possibility as to recompile or relink by hand. Maybe you will have luck with Python installation you have (probably from brew or macports). Execute `$ otool -L /path/to/python/installation/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-*-darwin.so | grep libssl`. If you get the absolute path to `libssl.dylib`, then there is no way for you to change the lib without recompiling/relinking.

Comment: Ah, you can of course also move the original lib to some backup place and create a symlink to your custom lib file - if the system integrity protection will allow you to create the symlink. Also, it is often warned that this can brick your system if you are not careful enough...

Comment: I think what you see is otool is the file that was found in the current search path. Other shared library might be loaded due to executable running with some other environment variable.

Comment: And as for your other solution of creating symbolic link in /usr/lib64, I'd realy prefer not to mess with shared objects of the entire OS.

I suppose that the best solution is to compile another version of _ssl.so, and locate it in a different folder which will be added to PYTHONPATH when I want to use it.

(I can also use install_name_tool, but it doesn't feel right...)